# I'm unable to get Deep linking to respond in the swift iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, deep-linking

So I'm trying to get FB and Twitter to respond from tappin on a table cell:

I set up the plist:

[image]

Then I created this function:

```
 func schemeAvailable(scheme: String) -> Bool {
        if let url = URL(string: scheme) {
            return UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
        }
        return false
    }
```

Then I tried to use it:

```
  print(UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "fb:")!))

    if(schemeAvailable(scheme: "fb://")){
        print("facebook agailable")
    }
    if(schemeAvailable(scheme: "twitter://")){
        print("twitter agailable")
    }
```

and get back a response of:

```
2016-10-03 17:04:09.096 JSONTesting[73245:2492124] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb:" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
false
2016-10-03 17:04:09.097 JSONTesting[73245:2492124] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
2016-10-03 17:04:09.098 JSONTesting[73245:2492124] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "twitter://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

I've tried with and without the // in the string but to no avail...get the same error back every time.

Thanks

Comment: Those apps aren't installed in the simulator.

Comment: is there any way to test it then?

Comment: Of course. Test on a real iOS device. You need to do that for many reason anyway.